# icCube dateTime format and Excel PivotTable TimeLine

Tags: iccube

I have a flat file datasource that I'm using to construct a Dimension. One of the columns is a DateTime in the format: yyyy.MM.dd HH:MM, which I specified as the 'Date Converter Pattern'.

However, when I connect to my cube using an Excel Pivot Table, the date format defaults to: yyyy-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss.SSS and when I try to create a Timeline on my PivotTable, excel does not recognize this as a valid DateTime format.

is there any way to change this in the config files

thanks

Comment: The date format for the input data is not related to the export format (that should be Excel compatible), are you using a standard pivot table connections (SSAS) ?

Comment: Are those for values or for members ?

Comment: yes, using a standard pivot table with ssas connection type.  These are members. It's the last level of a dimension hierarchy.

Comment: I realized that I can probably just add a column to my datasource that would be the DateTime in the format that I want to see in Excel and not specify a Date Converter Pattern. It would then propagate through to Excel as a String but will probably work with the TimeLine feature

Comment: Let us check how the Excel handles dates in the members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a TimeLine Excel is using several DISCOVER requests and is more or less assuming it is talking to SSAS to discover an " attribute " hierarchy. Support has been added into icCube (from 6.0.1) to flag a hierarchy as an Excel TimeLine (new field in the hierarchy definition): this hierarchy must have an ALL level and a single DATE (i.e., days) level below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit lost, I understand you've converted to a DateTime the strings from the data source. Why do you see 'yyyy-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss.SSS' as the member names/labels ?

You can choose whatever you want to ?

My educated guess, Excel is taking for the timeline the key of the member not the label (that needs to be a DateTime object in the datasource).

Can you clarify ?

Comment: I don't think Excel is using the key (in my case the key is an integer). My source data is a flat file where one of the columns, called StartDate, is in the format yyyy.MM.DD HH:MM (it's coming like this from a 3rd party application). In my DataSource Table definition I specified the Date Converter Pattern field as yyyy.MM.DD HH:MM. I then create a dimension (same as your your example) where the last level in the heirarchy is StartDate. When I then connect to the cube from Excel and put StartDate into the row of the pivot table, the values are formatted as 'yyyy-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss.SSS'

Comment: they could use names instead, but the example is one of a valid SASS structure in Excel

Comment: Thanks. For now I'll just pre-process the datasource file to add a column that has an Excel recognized format and will see how that works.

Comment: actually Excel knows there is no 'time' dimension before doing any request, now playing hacker and trying to find the differences ;-)

Comment: thanks.  I tried to add an additional column to the source data that's in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm and keep it formatted as a String in icCube but that doesn't work on the Excel side -- it passes through as a String as well and Excel can't recognize it as a DateTime.

Comment: Really looks as Excel is using some schema metadata to build the timeline, it's not based on measures neither on the actual key or member structure (for now i guess later on we might have the problem :-) )

Comment: I don't think it's an Excel issue. Even when I execute the mdx query in the icCube user interface, the DateTime result is still returned as:

Comment: We should continue by email, but you can try to get a TimeLine filter before any request. That is not working on my version

Comment: what email should i use?  Also, realized that my last comment got cut off but I meant to say that even when I run the mdx query on the icCube user interface, the DateTime format is still using the 'yyyy-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss.SSS' format. I think if this could be changed somehow, it would pass through to Excel and be recognized as a valid DateTime. To test, I tried importing data into Excel directly from a SQL server database and in this case, DateTime values are recognized correctly.

Comment: use support at iccube